# How to grab 10 most recently created profiles in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Well i am want to show most recent created profiles but i dont understand how can i grab them by queryset. I am adding some information if more information require than tell me i will update my answer with that information

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True,)
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
   
    objects = ProfileManager()


    class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def top_profile(self):
        top_profile = self.get_queryset().get(user=self.request.user)
        qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(
                                user=top_profile
                                ).order_by('-create_date')[:10]
        return top_profile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
  def most_recent(self):
    return self.get_queryset().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

Alternatively, you can add `created_at` field to `UserProfile`:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  ...
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
  def most_recent(self):
    return self.get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')[:10]
```

Comment: what if i want to show top 10 profiles which have most followers? How can we do that ?

Comment: @FlashMaddy `UserProfile.objects.annotate(num_followers=Count('follower')).order_by('-num_followers')[:10]`.
Where `Count` is `from django.db.models import Count`

Comment: How can we paginate this ? right now i am trying to paginate this with `paginate_by=2` and this is not working. this is still showing 10 all together